# Merge excel sheets header into one and remove duplicates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Is there any way we can merge all excel sheets header into one and remove the duplicate column in vb.net

I am uploading excel sheets to access database in vb.net. But there are duplicate columns across sheets. So i am thinking of upload header first then datas.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Yes it can be done. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok, i tried _command.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [" & dbpath & "].[Sheet1] FROM [Sheet1$]" for all sheet1 data, but i need to upload all sheets, to avoid duplicates, i will look to upload header first then data i will upload.